# How can i show/hide specific content from user location?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to show some content to only local users. There are some API is available but i don't know how can i do that. 
A similar thing like Google ads do, they show some ads as per your locality. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the user IP address.
2. Use this an API to get the country using the IP address.
3. Store the country.
4. Do some `if` statements

Here is a free location API 
http://ip-api.com/docs/